# Don't want to enter the password on git prompt for each and every git pull/push operation

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

Basically I am trying to perform the git operations i.e git pull/git push to https:// from Git bash and don't want to enter password again and again asking on the prompt.

However I am not able to solve this thing on my windows 10 OS machine.

Things I have tried

- With git version 3.29.0, I have observed that the Git Credential Manager(GCM) is asking for the prompt for every git pull./push
- As per many stack overflow posts, I tried by downgrading the git version 3.29.0 to 3.28.1 so that Git Credential manager don't ask for password for each and every git pull/push

  - However on downgrading the git version to 3.28.0, now I am getting the password prompt from 'Git for Windows' for password

I want to bypass entering the password for each and every git pull/push.

With git version 3.28.0 -> `git config --global credential.helper manager-core` (not working)

Also tried using `git config --global credential.helper cache`

but after hitting the above command I am getting this error:

> credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support

```bash
$ git pull

fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
```

Also tried with git credential store and it also gave below error
`git config credential.helper` store:

```bash
$ git pull

fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
```

Want to bypass the git bash prompt in Microsoft Windows 10 password again and again

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-cache-https-credentials-for-pushing-commits/5343146#5343146. Note that for GitHub you need to use a PAT (not a password) for https remotes, or (much better) switch to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your SSH key to sign your interactions between your computer and your GitHub/GitLab/GitWhatever account. This is the GitHub documentation, but there is pretty the process on your computer is not related to the git platform used, and I think you can find the same kind of documentation for the other platforms.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh

Then, I guess you tried to push to your own repository, so use the `git://...` url instead of the https one.